# Using LaTeX in a Web page created in HTML

Tags: symbols, equations

I am creating a web page related Mathematics.  So, while scripting if I use Latex like $$\frac{x^2+y}{\sqrt{x^4-x^2+47}}$$, the output I see is same. Can anyone help me out from this problem? By the by I don't want to embed the equation.

Comment: What? Why do you expect that a LaTeX notation would be interpreted by LaTeX rules on an HTML page? And what do you want if you do not want to embed the equation?

Comment: While [tag:MathJax] uses LaTeX syntax, it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology, making it mostly off topic for this site. You might try instead searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/mathjax-users) Google group.